# pgfmath: How to create a '10^n sep' like '1000 sep'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

We know, there is a command `1000 sep={...}`.

Is it possible, to create a command like `10^11 sep={\\}`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, 1000 sep={\,}]{1233123312331233123312}

\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, 1000 sep={\,}]{123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Short answer: no. If you ask whether or not it is possible to add a `\\ ` after 11 characters automatically, the answer is yes. But to marry this to something that respects all other number format options is nontrivial.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try this at home - you have been warned

```
\def\mysepfinish#1{#1\ifnum\count0>\count1
 \let\next\mysepfinish
 \advance\count0by-1\relax
 \count2=\count0
 \divide\count2by\count1
 \multiply\count2by\count1\relax
 \ifnum\count2=\count0\relax\mydelim\fi
 \else\let\next\relax\fi\next}
\def\mysepcount#1{\ifx\end#1\let\next\relax
 \else\advance\count0by1\let\next\mysepcount\fi
 \next}
\def\mysep#1#2#3{{\def\mydelim{#2}\count0=0\relax
 \count1=#1\relax
 \mysepcount#3\end
 \mysepfinish#3\relax}}

\mysep{11}{\\}{1234567890123456789012345678901234567890}
```

Comment: Why do you say that? Lol!